# Mongo Replica: Is it possible to add a member that doesn't have any effect on elections and availability?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have a replica set with 3 members that will continue functioning if 1 of 3 goes down. Now, I need to add another secondary member to a replica, which I want to be optional to the replica in all regards. I'm curious if priority: 0 + votes: 0 will do the trick or not.

That new replica member can go down fairly likely and frequently, and I want to configure it in a way, that will still allow 1 other member to go down (in addition to a new one) and still keep the replica set working (i.e., with 2 out of 4 members, but with 2 out of 3 votes). In other words, I don't want the new member to negatively affect the replica set availability.

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of this replica set member? Maybe just lower the priority. Note, for an even number of nodes (4 in your case) you should also add an [arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/).

Comment: Current replica uses 2 data-bearing nodes and an arbiter in the same datacenter. The idea is to have another data-bearing secondary in a separate datacenter as a live backup "just in case". That secondary for now should only operate as a backup

Comment: For "backup only", you should create a [Hidden Member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/) However, if you have a PSA (PRIMARY, SECONDARY, ARBITER) replica set, then I would suggest to remove the ARBITER and add simple SECONDARY, i.e. (PSS, PRIMARY, SECONDARY, SECONDARY). But lower priority on the new data bearing node if it goes down fairly likely and frequently.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, though frankly I would like to keep current 3 nodes as they are to allow one of data-bearing nodes to go down regardless of the status of that new node. I hope it makes sense. I will consider your suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the member to votes=0,priority=0,hidden=true and you can stop/start any time without replicaSet or applications to understand ...

Comment: Hi R2D2, thank you for the reply. To clarify: are you sure that in that setup if this node is stopped and one another node goes down, replica is going to be still alive? Replica sets require a majority to elect a primary. The question is "Is a member or a vote majority?".

Comment: In general election happen between voting members only , so if votes=0  the member will not participate in the election process.

Comment: But setting it hiddin is best since this way the  application will not see it so no calls will be sent to it and best suitable for backups